# I have downloaded Eclipse and tried to create a sample servlet program but I got following error

Tags: java, servlets

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is 
     indirectly referenced from required .class files
    - The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is 
     indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I have configured build path correctly. I am using Java 8 update 111 and Apache Tomcat 7 and libraries for both are referenced correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `o` and see if it does the magic?